# Convert XML formats to be compatible with Access Import

Tags: xml, vba, xslt

This is related to a previous post. I am trying to import Economic-data from StLouisFred into Access. I will ultimately use this database for excel. I'm a student, and this task, albeit easy, is above my experience. I also tried to import the XML data into Excel, however, the formatting is still an issue. I know FRED uses CSV, but you can't automatically update CSV, so I want to use XML. The data is formatted like follows:

```
 <observations realtime_start="2013-02-08" realtime_end="2013-02-08"  
 observation_start="1776-07-04" observation_end="9999-12-31" units="lin"   
 output_type="2" file_type="xml" order_by="observation_date" sort_order="asc" 
 count="792" offset="0"        limit="100000">
 <observation date="1947-01-01" CPIAUCSL_20130208="21.48"/>
 <observation date="1947-02-01" CPIAUCSL_20130208="21.62"/>
 <observation date="1947-03-01" CPIAUCSL_20130208="22.0"/>
 </observations>
```

I am trying to convert the data into the other standard xml format that Access prefers. Something like this:

```
<observations realtime_start="2013-02-08" realtime_end="2013-02-08"  
 observation_start="1776-07-04" observation_end="9999-12-31" units="lin"   
 output_type="2" file_type="xml" order_by="observation_date" sort_order="asc" 
 count="792" offset="0"        limit="100000">

 <observation> 
 <date> 1947-01-01 </date>
 <value> 21.48 </value> 
 <observation/>

 <observation> 
 <date>1947-02-01</date> 
 <value>21.62</value>
 </observation>

 <observation> 
 <date>1947-03-01</date> <value>22.0</value>
 </observation>

 </observations>
```

It seems that this would work. Access has the ability to use a style sheet, which I'd be happy to try, but I'd need a slight walkthrough. Thus, suppose I have a sheet of information in the first xml-format. Is there a way for me to convert the data into Access so that I can have a table that will be automatically updated, or is this a hopeless project?

Comment: It looks as through you want to convert the attributes of the <observation> nodes into child nodes of the <observation> nodes and also rename one of the nodes while doing so. The standard way of doing this is with XSLT so I've added that tag to the question

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a simple XSLT transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="observation/@date">
  <date><xsl:value-of select="."/></date>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="observation/@*[starts-with(name(),'CPIAUCSL_')]">
  <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<observations realtime_start="2013-02-08"
     realtime_end="2013-02-08"
     observation_start="1776-07-04"
     observation_end="9999-12-31" units="lin"
     output_type="2" file_type="xml"
     order_by="observation_date" sort_order="asc"
     count="792" offset="0"        limit="100000">
    <observation date="1947-01-01" CPIAUCSL_20130208="21.48"/>
    <observation date="1947-02-01" CPIAUCSL_20130208="21.62"/>
    <observation date="1947-03-01" CPIAUCSL_20130208="22.0"/>
</observations>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<observations realtime_start="2013-02-08"
 realtime_end="2013-02-08" observation_start="1776-07-04"
 observation_end="9999-12-31" units="lin" output_type="2"
 file_type="xml" order_by="observation_date" sort_order="asc"
 count="792" offset="0" limit="100000">
   <observation>
      <date>1947-01-01</date>
      <value>21.48</value>
   </observation>
   <observation>
      <date>1947-02-01</date>
      <value>21.62</value>
   </observation>
   <observation>
      <date>1947-03-01</date>
      <value>22.0</value>
   </observation>
</observations>
```